# Rubymine: Change Code Language

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I'm working with a file that is one type (php), but the code is predominantly another language (html). Is there a way that I can switch the syntax highlighting (if that's what it's called) from php to html?

Comment: RubyMine does not have PHP support. So you must be using one of the Textmate bundled for that. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I get that. I want it to look like HTML though, which is in Rubymine.

Comment: So .. how do you see PHP syntax highlighting in RubyMine of IDE does not have support for php files/syntax?

Comment: In any case: you can associate `*.php` pattern (or whatever else pattern you think would be better) to `HTML files` in `Settings | File Types` -- this will affect ALL files that matching that pattern in ALL projects (as this is an IDE-wide settings). RubyMine cannot switch from one file type / syntax to another on the fly / when desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

associate *.php as PHP files, and DONE
[image]

Comment: There should be a one-time way to do this.   There are time I really want to override the FileTypes for right now.